# How do I mock the Python method OptionParser.error(), which does a sys.exit()?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, optparse

I'm trying to unit test some code that looks like this:

```
def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(description='This tool is cool', prog='cool-tool')
    parser.add_option('--foo', action='store', help='The foo option is self-explanatory')
    options, arguments = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.foo:
        parser.error('--foo option is required')
    print "Your foo is %s." % options.foo
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
   sys.exit(main())
```

With code that looks like this:

```
@patch('optparse.OptionParser')
def test_main_with_missing_p4clientsdir_option(self, mock_optionparser):
    #
    # setup
    #
    optionparser_mock = Mock()
    mock_optionparser.return_value = optionparser_mock
    options_stub = Mock()
    options_stub.foo = None
    optionparser_mock.parse_args.return_value = (options_stub, sentinel.arguments)
    def parser_error_mock(message):
        self.assertEquals(message, '--foo option is required')
        sys.exit(2)
    optionparser_mock.error = parser_error_mock

    #
    # exercise & verify
    #
    self.assertEquals(sut.main(), 2)
```

I'm using [Michael Foord's Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock.html), and nose to run the tests.

When I run the test, I get:

```
  File "/Users/dspitzer/Programming/Python/test-optparse-error/tests/sut_tests.py", line 27, in parser_error_mock
    sys.exit(2)
SystemExit: 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.012s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The problem is that OptionParser.error does a sys.exit(2), and so main() naturally relies on that.  But nose or unittest detects the (expected) sys.exit(2) and fails the test.

I can make the test pass by adding "return 2" under the parser.error() call in main() and removing the sys.exit() call from parser_error_mock(), but I find it distasteful to modify the code under test to allow a test to pass.  Is there a better solution?

**Update**: [df](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002/df)'s answer works, although the correct call is "self.assertRaises(SystemExit, sut.main)".

Which means the test passes whatever the number is in the sys.exit() in parser_error_mock(). Is there any way to test for the exit code?

BTW, the test is more robust if I add:

```
self.assertEquals(optionparser_mock.method_calls, [('add_option', ('--foo',), {'action': 'store', 'help': 'The foo option is self-explanatory'}), ('parse_args', (), {})])
```

at the end.

**Update 2**: I can test for the exit code by replacing "self.assertRaises(SystemExit, sut.main)" with:

```
try:
    sut.main()
except SystemExit, e:
    self.assertEquals(type(e), type(SystemExit()))
    self.assertEquals(e.code, 2)
except Exception, e:
    self.fail('unexpected exception: %s' % e)
else:
    self.fail('SystemExit exception expected')
```

Comment: The first assertEquals on your Update 2 is unnecessary, since the "except" line above it will only catch SystemExit exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my updates to my question, I had to modify [dF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002/df)'s answer to:

```
self.assertRaises(SystemExit, sut.main)
```

...and I came up with a few longer snippet to test for the exit code.

[Note: I accepted my own answer, but I will delete this answer and accept [dF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002/df)'s if he updates his.]

Answer (score 12):

Will this work instead of `assertEquals`?

```
self.assertRaises(SystemExit, sut.main, 2)
```

This should catch the `SystemExit` exception and prevent the script from terminating.

Comment: I've "unaccepted" your answer, since it's not quite correct.  But since you gave me the insight that led me to the answer (see the updates to the question), I'll give you a couple days to edit your answer and then I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this question contains some new information:

[Java: How to test methods that call System.exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit)

Comment: I read it quickly and while it's the same problem (in Java), I didn't see anything applicable here (to Python).  Do you?

Answer (score 0):

Add `@raises` to your test function. I.e:

```
from nose.tools import raises

@raises(SystemExit)
@patch('optparse.OptionParser')
def test_main_with_missing_p4clientsdir_option(self, mock_optionparser):
    # Setup
    ...
    sut.main()
```