# What are the security risks I should guard against when running user-supplied Java code?

Tags: java

Is there a comprehensive list of the security issues with running user-supplied Java code on a server? I'm already

- using timeouts of 10 seconds
- running code in a separate process with limited available memory
- using SecurityMangager to prevent File and Network IO
- running code under an account with extremely limited filesystem permissions

I'm running this on a FreeBSD server if that matters.

Comment: Even if there were a comprehensive list, it would likely be outdated the moment it was published.

Comment: Are you worried about denial of service?  Does the JVM process inherit file descriptors from its parent process?  How have you limited the Classpath?  Can the user-supplied Java call `System.loadLibrary`?

Comment: Finally, whenever I hear of someone running Java from an untrusted source, I have to ask, "are you aware of [Joe-E](http://code.google.com/p/joe-e/) and if not, could you run only code that passes the Joe-E verifier instead?

Comment: Thanks @MikeSamuel -- Joe-E looks alright, except for the Eclipse dependency. If there was a way to run the verifier w/o any use of Eclipse, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a very good start - Security Manager is essential for sandboxing a whole bunch of other stuff you don't mention explicitly (like preventing the user from disabling the Security Manager, of course, and being able to invoke arbitrary commands, or use native code, or get the OS to exec files etc). I assume you are starting from zero permissions and just granting the explicit permissions needed.

Security Manager can't deal with denial-of-service through excessive resource usage, but your other controls probably address this (prevent network connections, control disk usage, timeouts to prevent CPU hogging - if that's what you meant by timeouts).

You say "extremely limited filesystem permissions" - hopefully this also includes disk quota? are you running multiple untrusted processes, and do they share disk space? Running out of file handles might be an issue (not sure how these are managed for a limited account).

There are still occasional JVM vulnerabilities, so the risk depends on what else is on the server, and what the consequences of a problem actually are (how bad is it if you have to wipe the server?).

See also: [Sandbox against malicious code in a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application) and [Execute external Java source code on server - limit security and resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456109/execute-external-java-source-code-on-server-limit-security-and-resources)

Answer (score 1):

The question I'd ask myself is, 'How much do I trust the people, and how much do I trust that their code won't break my system?'  In general, my answer would be not much, and not as far as I could throw 'em.  But, off the top of my head, here are some things I would want to guard against.

- Infinite loops (timeouts help)
- Dodgy I/O operations (trying to read/write from/to directories they have no access to)
- Privilege escalation code (limiting the account to only be able to execute in a specific context, or with specific permissions is a huge plus)
- Creation of too many objects/removing memory (limiting available memory and/or resources is a plus here)
- Reading/writing from/to a socket and not releasing the resource
- Expecting input from STDIN, which may be problematic if the server is headless

There are *plenty* more to be wary for, so I would tread carefully.  Safeguard each account and `/home` directory from one another as best as you can (a simple `chmod 700 $HOME` will often do it), and experiment with code that you would consider dodgy before deploying publicly.  Once you're comfortable with how well the server holds up, allow others to test your server and see how well it goes.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I think that in this day and age one pretty strong solution to the problem would be to run the code inside a Docker. At least, if a destructive script is sent to the Docker, you only lose the Docker.

You should then consider updating the code whenever a hack happens so you can (hopefully) avoid it next time. At least, the rest of your server will be safe that way. Run the VM system inside the docker with a port to which you can send the scripts to run. That way you can also keep track of all the scripts being run on the host and thus have a copy of the possibly offensive scripts if that Docker gets hacked.

All the other features you and the others mentioned would be useful too since that way you prevent *easy* crashing of the Docker and you can also block users trying to hack the system.