# Ignore System.exit() from other class

Tags: java

Given the class below,

```
public class ClassOne {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

The following class will be destroyed as well, assuming there are other things to do after ClassOne.main is invoked.

```
public class ClassTwo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ClassOne.main(args);
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to ignore the System.exit(1); of ClassOne in ClassTwo's invocation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to test methods that call System.exit()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't ignore it *per se*, but you can prevent it from terminating the JVM via SecurityManager.
Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit) for detailed code example.

Comment: Sorry but what is _se_ ("You can't ignore it per _se_")?

Comment: "per se" is Latin meaning "as such". In other words, you can't ignore the `System.exit()` as if it never happened, but you can prevent it from terminating the JVM, and the `exit()` call will instead throw a Security Exception. However, I wonder if this exception could kill the system in some cases...

Comment: So what if the other class then re-enables it?