# security problem with Java ScriptEngine

Tags: java, scripting, permissions, sandbox

I just started to use the Java ScriptEngine to do little extensions to my Application then i noticed that i can import all the java classes in the script and use them without restrictions. Is there a way to specify what classes a script can use? I dont want them to do things like `java.lang.System.exit(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you seem to need to learn about the Java SecurityManager. That's a pretty large topic, you might want to read up on it and then post a more specific question if you have trouble making it work for you.

Comment: SecuritiyManager sounds good i will look at it. Do you have any hints for me where to start on this big topic?

Comment: SecurityManager is now deprecated in Java 17 (https://openjdk.org/jeps/411). What do we do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Java Security Manager. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit/309427#309427)  answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by putting "importPackage = null" on the top of all scripts, it seems to work but Im not sure if this hack can be avoided.

Comment: looks like this is the easiest way to restrict all importPackage calls

Comment: In this case it is still possible to do something like this: `java.lang.System.exit(1);`. Program will exit.