# Can I use a char to do calculation in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible for me to do something like the following below in order to save time from doing if else statement?

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
char z = '+';

System.out.println(x + z + y); //e.g. 1 + 2 i.e. 3
```

Please advise.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. In your expression, the `'+'` char is converted to its `int` value. (The result of that expression would be `46`: 1 + 43 + 2).

You'd have to use an `if` (or `switch`) statement:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
char z = '+';

if (z == '+') System.out.println(x + y);
else if (z == '-') System.out.println(x - y);
// else if (z == '*') ... and so on
```

If you are only interested in the result, you can evaluate the `String` directly using Java's JavaScript `ScriptEngine`:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
public class Eval {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager s = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = s.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;
        char z = '+';

        String exp = "" + x + z + y;
        System.out.println(engine.eval(exp));
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
3.0
```

<sub>**Note:** [there can be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878052/security-problem-with-java-scriptengine) some issues with the use of `ScriptEngine`. So do not allow the user to enter the expression to be evaluated directly. Using with variables (`x`, `y` and `z` like you do) takes care of this problem, though.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

No, that wouldn't work as expected. (it will compile and run, but since the unicode value of `+` is 0x2B, or 43, and a `char` is treated like a number in this case, your expression `x + z + y` evaluates to `1 + 43 + 2`, so it prints 46) You can use `if`/`else` or `switch` statements to evaluate what operation to do, which would work for simple inputs, or you can look at a more general expression parsing library, e.g. [exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/index.html) or [jexel](https://code.google.com/p/jexel/).

Answer (score 0):

That will compile but not run in the way you expect.

z will be converted to an int, which will be that character's value in the default charset (most likely ASCII).

As an example, on my computer that results in "46"

Answer (score 0):

The output should be `1 + 2 + 43 = 46`

For char, it will take the Ascii value of '+'