# Load external resource/API

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, xpath

I have a lib, which has a API available under `uk.ac.ox.cs.diadem.oxpath.oxpath-example`

In java I would use it like so

`// load from API
package uk.ac.ox.cs.diadem.oxpath.oxpath-example;
// invoke OXPath
OXPath.ENGINE.evaluate(input, browser, outputHandler);`

The complete documentation can be found [here](http://www.oxpath.org/papers/2017-IntroductionToOxpath-ed1.pdf). Page 30 (last paragraph before section 3.2) says I can embed it in JavaScript, but there is only a java example.

How can I load OXPath into a JavaScript project?

EDIT

I have tried this:

```js
var oxpath = require("uk.ac.ox.cs.diadem.oxpath"); // error
```

But it throws an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'uk.ac.ox.cs.diadem.oxpath'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please explain more about your use-case?**

"Introduction to OXPath" document provided in your question is not available anymore. This could be because a more recent version have been released in 2018.

Please see here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.10899.pdf

Referring to this document, in section 3.7, page 43 reads:

> ```
> Different components of OXPath are united under the umbrella name OXPath Project.
> The current version of OXPath (2.2.0) and OXPath CLI (1.0.1) are generated by OXPath
> Project 1.0.3. It consists of the following main components:
> OXPath Core (v.2.2.0) implementing the core functionality of the OXPath language.
> WebAPI (v.1.4.0) implementing an interface to web browsers based on Selenium 2.53.1
> (only Firefox 47.0.1 is currently supported).
> Output Handlers are a set of modules for serialising the output tree of OXPath into
> different formats. The following output handlers are available: XMLOutputHandler
> for XML (see Section 1.3.1 on page 13), JsonOutputHandler for JSON (see Section 1.3.2 on page 13), RecStreamCSVOutputHandler for rscsv
> ```
>
> (see Section 1.3.3
>       on page 14), HierarchyCSVOutputHandler for hcsv,
>       RecStreamJDBCOutputHandler for rsjdbc (see Section 1.3.4 on page 16), and
>       HierarchyJDBCOutputHandler for hjdbc.
>       OXPath CLI (v.1.0.1) is a command line interface for OXPath.
>       Java documentation API is available at https://oxpath.github.io/api-docs/1.0.
>       3/javadoc/.

I don't think there is a Javascript API currently, but they could be referring to the fact that you can use java classes into javascript. See here: [Use a jar in JavaScript through Java ScriptEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577613/use-a-jar-in-javascript-through-java-scriptengine)

However, considering that the underlaying engine relies on selenium opening a browser and navigating the various URL's in your OXPath query, even when using X video frame buffer, **OXPath would be unusable in any client code environment**