# Restrict some API in Embedded Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, sandbox

I just embedded Groovy in my application and wondering if it's possible to restrict access to some APIs i.e. java.io.File, java.net.URL, etc

Or instead of completely restricting java.io.File access, I want to ONLY allow access to certain directories on the machine.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Java Security Manager. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit/309427#309427) answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Java security and the [policy file](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html) ? I suspect setting [FilePermission](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html) will do what you want.

Comment: a quick look at the link shows that I can "grant" permission to a file directory. However, is it possible to "ungrant" permission?