# Assert statement causing JUnit tests to stop

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

In the class I am testing, there are a few assert statements that check for various conditions.

One of the methods is

```
GetNames(string id){
    assert(! id.Equals("")); // Causes all junit tests to stop
    ...
}
```

and there is an assert statement to check if id is not blank.

In my unit tests, I have one test where I pass it a blank string, and a few others. The problem is that when the assert statement gets executed in the class, the JUnit tests stop running after that test case.

How can I change/setup the unit tests so that if there is an assertion failure in the class, the tests do not stop.

I have to enable the assertions in order for the code to run properly since there are cases where variables are incremented in the assertions. Unfortunately, I cannot change any of the code.

I am using the JUnit plugin in eclipse. I do not have any code in the setup and teardown sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `assert` statements in the code being tested, and assertions are [enabled](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable), then those statements will be causing an [`AssertionError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) to be thrown. You can catch that in your test code and ignore it:

```
try {
    xxx.GetNames("");
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    // this is expected - ignore it
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized the code which is causing the tests to stop actually calls "system.exit(1)". Is there a way to still run the unit tests after system.exit has been called?

Comment: No, it causes the VM to terminate. What is the code that you're testing? Any library code that calls `System.exit` is broken.

Comment: Actually, you could write your own `SecurityManager` that prohibits a call to `System.exit`. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit

Comment: If the intent is to verify that the exception is thrown, you need to call `fail()` after calling `GetNames`. If the intention is to ignore the assertion failure, then whatever `GetNames` does might not have been completed, so it would be questionable to do that in a test (where you wanted to know the intended state of your objects before you make assertions)