# How to test executable JAR?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a simple class in executable JAR file:

```
public final class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello, world!");
    System.exit(-1);
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to test this class/method:

```
public class MainTest {
  @Test public void testMain() {
    Main.main(new String[] { "something" });
  }
}
```

Testing crashes on `System.exit(0)`, and I can understand why. Now what should I do? Shall I mock `System`? What is a standard approach here? Btw, maybe I should test the method "in container" (read "in JAR"), the same way we're doing it with WAR files?

Comment: Why are you calling `System.exit()` at all?

Comment: I changed the question. I'm calling `System.exit(-1)`. This just an example, in my real-life project everything is much more complex, of course

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a security police or a Security Manager that does not allow the Virtual Machine to be terminated by `exit`.

```
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkExit(int status) {
            throw new AccessControlException("exit not allowed during testing");
        }
    });
```

A possible drawback is that a call to `exit` will throw an Exception,

See [java.lang.SecurityManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) and [Permissions in the JDK](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html) for details.

(*I do not like the idea of calling `exit` - kind of a harsh way to stop the Virtual Machine.*)

Answer (score 1):

Use of [AspectJ around advice](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-advice.html) could possibly work here, as you would be able to intercept the call to `System.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main shouldn't call System.exit(0); if it didn't it would make no difference, except you can call it in a test.

Or you shouldn't test the main, as you don't actually check anything it does.

EDIT: In the past I have gone with the suggestion to use a SecurityManager to prevent System.exit() shutting down the unit test.  However, over the last few years I have just made sure not to use System.exit() for many reasons including this one.

Comment: Pleas, see my comment above and the changes I made to the question