# Preventing JVM from executing System.exit()

Tags: java

how to prevent from executing System.exit(). If in middle of code exit() method is called. JVM should throw compile time exception

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401281/preventing-system-exit-from-api)

Comment: There's no such thing as a "compile time exception".

Answer (score 2):

[does this thread help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549720/how-to-prevent-calls-to-system-exit-from-terminating-the-jvm)

Otherwise/In short, you could implement your own Security Manager like this:

```
class MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
  @Override public void checkExit(int status) {
    throw new SecurityException();
  }
}
```