# Java SecurityManager

Tags: java

I just tried to use an empty Security File.

Although, `System.exit(0);` does work.

Is there a way to eliminate this?

We're calling SecurityManager via CLI with our own empty policy file. And if I try `System.exit(0);` in the main function, and after it some System.out or whatever, it will exit.  I want to deny any System commands. We're going to include Code from another user soon, so it's bad, if the user can shut down the whole framework.

Comment: Could you elaborate with some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to prevent `System.exit()` from exiting the JVM process by supplying your custom security manager. Are you allowed to programatically set the `SecurityManager`? If yes, you might find a few interesting suggestions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549720/how-to-prevent-calls-to-system-exit-from-terminating-the-jvm).