# how do I test app exit with jemmy

Tags: java, swing, testing, jemmy

I use Jemmy for Java GUI testing. Is it possible to test closing application?

Currently I simulate a click on the exit button (causing `System.exit(0)`) and the test fails:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit.
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)
```

Thanks,
Andrey

Comment: You might want to try the SecurityManager approach described in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141252/dealing-with-system-exit0-in-junit-tests).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with System.exit(0) in JUnit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141252/dealing-with-system-exit0-in-junit-tests)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially override security manager and check that System.exit() is going to happen.

[Java: How to test methods that call System.exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it with an Action from the File menu and Exit.

```
        Action action = new Action("File|Exit", null);
        action.perform();
```