# Gradle build fail: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, gradle

Gradle build fails when it gets to the **:test** task (junit tests).  It gives the error

```
Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I am using gradle with a java project in eclipse.  Gradle 1.12 and Java 7.  The problem seems to be happening when a test is run on a class that connects to a database.  The odd thing is that the program and tests work fine as java applications.  There are no problems with the database connection and it compiles and runs correctly.  Does gradle do something that could mess with how it connects to external database servers?  The problem could have nothing to do with the database so any solution is appreciated.  I've looked online and on the official gradle site but nothing was helpful.  Thanks.

EDIT

Debug results:

```
14:23:28.661 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
14:23:28.661 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Test Run PASSED
14:23:28.665 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':test'
14:23:28.665 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :test FAILED
14:23:28.665 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :test (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 5.552 secs.
14:23:28.666 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 6.67 secs, idle: 0.021 secs
14:23:28.808 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
14:23:28.808 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
14:23:28.808 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
14:23:28.808 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 11.75 secs
14:23:28.811 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Error Message:

```
Unexpected exception thrown.
org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:51041'.
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:88)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionReceive.run(MessageHub.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.fill(Input.java:141)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:159)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readByte(Input.java:255)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(InterHubMessageSerializer.java:64)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(InterHubMessageSerializer.java:53)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:83)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketInputStream.read(SocketConnection.java:167)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.fill(Input.java:139)
    ... 10 more
Unexpected exception thrown.
org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not write message [EndOfStream] to '/127.0.0.1:51041'.
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.dispatch(SocketConnection.java:115)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionDispatch.run(MessageHub.java:279)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketOutputStream.flush(SocketConnection.java:230)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.dispatch(SocketConnection.java:113)
    ... 5 more
 FAILED
```

Comment: Without a way to reproduce, this will be hard to diagnose remotely. Looks like all tests are passing, and then something goes wrong when tearing down the JVM(s) that are running the tests. (Each `Test` task spins up one or more JVMs to run tests in.)

Answer (score 43):

Try cleaning your daemons with `./gradlew --stop`. It works for me.
This was my error. also sometimes I got an IDLE at the end of the build and never ends.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
```

Comment: In my case I'm still facing error.

Answer (score 21):

Most probably one of your test go through a `System.exit(1)`.

It may help to display the test result in console using `test -i`.

Comment: In my case I had a specific test to taskkill the JVM via its Pid. I found it was the culprit per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68864634/1964277) using `gradle test --tests houseKeeping.*` in which 1 test force killed the JVM. I fixed it by downgrading to `System.exit(0)` and using [junit5-system-exit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53264555/1964277) thanks @Todd

Comment: This was it for me. Had a cli command that was failing bad and interfering with app launch.

Answer (score 0):

check if your project its using internally Java 11 or Java 1.8 and the java that your system has:

to check your java version run:
`javac --version`

*Note that some IDEs may override that value to build.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue but it was caused by `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/dumps/
```

non existing path `/dumps/` caused the issue in my case.