# How to get the value that is passed to Runtime.getRuntime.exit(value) in a JUnit test case

Tags: java, junit, runtime, runtime.exec

I have to write a Test case in `JUnit` for a `Class` lets call it `C1` which internally calls `Runtime.getRuntime.exit(somevalue)`.

The class `C1` has a `main` method which accepts some `arguments` and the creates a `CommandLine` and then depending on the passed `arguments` does the specific tasks.

Now all tasks after executing call a `Runtime.getRuntime.exit(somevalue)`. The `somevalue` defines whether the task was executed successfully (means somevalue is 0) or had errors (means somevalue is 1).

In the JUnit test case of this I have to get this `somevalue` and check whether it is the desired `somevalue` or not.

How do I get the `somevalue` in the JUnit test case.

Comment: Are you using a mocking framework?

Comment: Simple JUnit Test Case classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override security manager to catch the exit code, if you use a mocking framework it would be more concise:

```
@Test
public void when_main_is_called_exit_code_should_be_1() throws Exception {
    final int[] exitCode = new int[1];
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkExit(int status) {
            exitCode[0] = status;
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }});

    try { main(); } catch(Exception e) {}

    assertEquals(exitCode[0], 1);
}

public static void main() {
    System.exit(1);
}
```