# How do set the error code (ErrorLevel) for an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, errorlevel

We are invoking an Eclipse RCP application through shell script. If Eclipse RCP application is exiting abnormally, then the ErrorLevel is not set properly due to which the shell is unable to identify the return code of the Eclipse RCP application.

Any ideas on how to set the %ErroLevel% through Eclipse RCP application ??

Comment: Sry..actually it is not a Java application, but an Eclipse application.. From within Eclipse Application, if I set the System.exit(value). This value is not displayed when I do echo %ERRORLEVEL%

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298705/exit-code-of-java-program-running-inside-of-the-eclipse-ide . Notice that `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(5)` is equal to `System.exit(5)`.

Comment: @BtcSources: yes, Both  System.exit(value) & Runtime.getRuntime().exit(5) are similar and after giving these in an Eclipse RCP appication, I'm still getting 0 as the ERROLEVEL

Comment: Kindly correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.....

Comment: Use a breakpoint to check if your program is ending within this line of code. It would be strange if it does but `ERRORLEVEL` doesn't change. Update the answer with two pics, the breakpoint stoped in runtime in the line, and the `<terminated, exit value: 10>` pic.

Comment: HI @BtcSources:  I coudn't update the pics as I don't have enough Reputations :( . 
But the line [ System.exit() ] is been executed and I'm able to view the Debug View 
<terminated, exit value: 10 >

Comment: For Normal Java application it seems to work ( I've verified this ) but not for an ECLIPSE APPLICATION

Comment: @BtcSources:  If you provide your mail ID then I can show you these PICS.

Comment: @BtcSources : Any idea on why it mis-behaves with an Eclipse RCP application ?   Actually for Java application it is working fine, whereas when comes to an Eclipse RCP application then it is not setting the ERRORLEVEL. Instead it is always setting as 0.

Comment: without seeing the result you're getting it's hard to say. Upload both pics to a server and update the post with their links please.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/account/home.jsp#dir=XmQnTOEc. You can find the attachments here in the above 4shared.com

Comment: man... your pic says the exit value is 10, as you've wrote in the `exit` function. It's working fine! http://dc97.4shared.com/img/uowOsN-Gba/s7/14d6c715038/terminate?async&rand=0.648259157504609

Comment: No it is not so, actually Im trying to invoke the RCP application from within a BAT script. So this errorlevel needs to be communicated b/w these 2 applications. but this is not happening. If I do the same thing with help of a NORMAL JAVA Application then it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

This should be simple: just add `System.exit(<your error code>);`

Example batch file:

```
java -classpath "%~dp0dist\StackOverflow3.jar" retvalue.RetValue
echo batch layer: %ErrorLevel%
pause
```

Example java source:

```
package retvalue;

public class RetValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("returning with 5"); 
        System.exit(5);
    }
}
```

console output:

```
C:\daten\chris\source\netbeans\StackOverflow3>java -classpath "C:\daten\chris\source\netbeans\StackOverflow3\dist\StackOverflow3.jar" retvalue.RetValue
returning with 5

C:\daten\chris\source\netbeans\StackOverflow3>echo batch layer: 5
batch layer: 5

C:\daten\chris\source\netbeans\StackOverflow3>pause
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Comment: I'm using an Eclipse RCP application and not a Java application

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it by using `System.Exit(value)` when you end your application. So a way would be to control your exceptions which make the program to finish abnormally, and then end the program using it to return the value you want for the `errorlevel`.

You can return the `int` value you want using it. As example:

```
// If I had IOException, then
System.exit(3);
```

Reference: [System.exit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

**Edit**: the problem you have about the number comes with the `%errorlevel%`value, use `ERRORLEVEL` instead, like:

```
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
  echo All ok
) else (
  echo An error
)
```

Just notice that ERRORLEVEL compares if `%errorlevel%` has a value equal or higher than the one you're giving to it.

Why do I say this? I've experienced the same problems than you before, that `%errorlevel%` seems to update later than when it must. I don't know the reason, but i can tell you that if you check it's value by `ERRORLEVEL`, you would check that this value is the correct one.

You only have to **check your higher values** returned **before**, since `ERRORLEVEL` checks if the value is equal or higher.

Reference: [%errorlevel% is not ERRORLEVEL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply !!.  I tried this but after exitting the program and doing echo %ErrorLEvel% still showing 0. and not the value which I'd set using System.exit(value)

Comment: That's problem of `%errorlevel%`, use `ERRORLEVEL` instead. Let me update my answer to show you how.

Comment: Hi.. Can you illustrate me how this can be achived.

Comment: @Ragu answer updated, you only have to check your higher values returned before, since `ERRORLEVEL` checks if the value is equal or higher.

Comment: My application is an eclipse applciation and not a Java appliocation. So It is with eclipse If I set the System.exit(value) then the same value is not updated with echo %ERRORLEVEL%

Answer (score 0):

You can set the error code that is returned by the JVM when the process exists using the [`System.exit(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-) call. For example:

```
System.exit(10);
```

This will end the JVM process with exit code 10.