# How to test a scenario that calls System.exit() in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, mocking, mockito

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to test methods that call System.exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit)

In a certain scenario, I want to test that the application makes a function call to send an email, and then calls `System.exit(0)`

This is a Java application, and Mockito is being used for mocking.

My test currently looks something like this:

```
testSendsEmailInScenario() {
  // set up

  foo.bar(mock);

  ArgumentCaptor<HashMap> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HashMap.class);
  verify(mockEmailDeliveryManager).send(argument.capture());
  Map<String,String> argMap = argument.getValue();
  // Test that map contains the right stuff
 }
```

So this doesn't work, because after the call to `send` in the application, `System.exit()` is called, which terminates the test without the test either succeeding or failing.

Since `exit()` is a static method of `System`, I can't mock it with Mockito. So how do I:

1. Suspend the exiting behavior for the sake of this test.
2. Write a second test that will confirm that the exit happened. (A test that succeeds only if `System.exit()` is called, and fails otherwise.)

Answer (score 1):

I use following very simple scenario: I use Groovy - MockFor which can guarantee for you that some method is called. I tried, it is working with even System classes.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm hoping not to bring in a new dependency. I'll keep it in mind though.