# Surefire fails because of checking if System.exit() was called in one of junit tests

Tags: java, groovy, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

To depict the problem I encountered, let's assume there is a dummy class:

```
import static java.lang.System.exit
class Example {

  void methodGeneratingSystemExit1() {
  exit 1
  }

  void methodGeneratingSystemExit2() {
  exit 2
  }
}
```

And a test against it:

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.ExpectedSystemExit
class ExampleTest {
@Rule
 public final ExpectedSystemExit expectedSystemExit = ExpectedSystemExit.none()

@Test
void "System exits with code 1 when method1 is generated"() {
expectedSystemExit.expectSystemExitWithStatus(1)
methodGeneratingSystemExit1()
}
@Test
void "System exits with code 1 when method1 is generated"() {
expectedSystemExit.expectSystemExitWithStatus(2)
methodGeneratingSystemExit2()
}


}
```

As I said, it's just dummy example but still test does what is supposed o do - when System.exit() is called, test notices that and is all green. The problem is, I have a surefire plugin that gives me a message like:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project xtrakter: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

How can I suppress that error in surefire? Or any other workaround/solution to that problem?

Comment: It looks like the Groovy code doesn't recognize the @Rule annotation.

Comment: Could you create a small example project and publish a link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surefire does not support tests or any referenced libraries calling System.exit() at any time.

source : http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#vm-termination

I think it's impossible to solve this problem, it's surefire core behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the same goes to failsafe plugin

Comment: There is a workaround to this, however - to install your own security manager.

Answer (score 4):

You can test for System.exit by installing your own [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkExit(int)), implementing the method *checkExit* for the duration of the test. See [Java: How to test methods that call System.exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit) for more details.