# The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

I write tests. I am using **Cucumber 6.8.1**, **TestNG 7.0.0**. For parallelization, I connected the **maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2** , **but I have not  paralleling tests right now, at the moment I'm running all tests only one by one**.

Most tests work good (about 45 tests). But there are several problematic tests, namely: when running such test, I get the error **"The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?"** Here is the full text:

[image]

I have searched in google this error. And I have read, that it is connected with the **maven-surefire-plugin**. In the Internet people offer different ways to solve this problem. For example, change the version of the maven plugin. At the moment I have version 2.22.2. I tried different versions: 3.0.0-M5, 3.0.0-M4, 3.0.0-M3, 3.0.0-M2, 3.0.0-M1, 2.22.1, 2.22.0, 2.21.0, 2.20. The result is the same: I get the error.

Also I have tried to write the argument
 **-Xmx1024m -XX: MaxPermSize = 256m** 
inside the maven-surefire-plugin config. It also didn't help.

And also I don't think, that this is due to the deficit of some resources. During the run of these problematic tests, monitoring does not show a particularly large consumption of resources:

[image]

Can you give to me some other ideas, please?

Comment: Did you refer to the dump file as the error message requests that you do?

Comment: And did you check that your code, or the code you are calling does not call `System.exit` anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log, **Crashed tests**, there is one test class which was not completed properly.  Try to find out what library or code is calling the
`System.exit()` or `Runtime.getRuntime.halt()`.
People have these problems with system exit due to the implementations of OSS libraries exit the process. Please see the [hint in stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034005/surefire-fails-because-of-checking-if-system-exit-was-called-in-one-of-junit-t) and try to find the evil with the help of **SystemManager** in Java.