# Scala: How to test methods that call System.exit()?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, specs2, testability

I have been developing a command-line tool which calls `System.exit()` (*don't want to use exceptions instead of*) on certain inputs.

I am familiar with [Java: How to test methods that call System.exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit) and its the most elegant [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658497/2077185).

Unfortunately, it is not enough pure, due to I had to add the dependencies to [system-rules](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules), [junit-interface](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface)

Is there any common pattern for dealing with `System.exit` in **specs2** which is more pure than my current approach which don't use **specs2**?

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.ExpectedSystemExit;

public class ConverterTest {
    @Rule
    public final ExpectedSystemExit exit = ExpectedSystemExit.none();

    @Test
    public void emptyArgs() {
        exit.expectSystemExit();
        Converter.main(new String[]{});
    }

    @Test
    public void missingOutArgument() {
        exit.expectSystemExitWithStatus(1);
        Converter.main(new String[]{"--in", "src/test/resources/078.xml.gz"});
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatest-users/pyKHtcP6HXM, where Bill Venners (author of ScalaTest) provides a helpful answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really wish to go with a method using `System.exit()`, the simplest way to test it was actually called is to replace your `SecurityManager` with one that'll throw an `ExitException` (subclassing `SecurityException`) when `System.exit()` is called:

class **SystemExitSpec**

```
import java.security.Permission

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.BeforeAfterAll

sealed case class ExitException(status: Int) extends SecurityException("System.exit() is not allowed") {
}

sealed class NoExitSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
  override def checkPermission(perm: Permission): Unit = {}

  override def checkPermission(perm: Permission, context: Object): Unit = {}

  override def checkExit(status: Int): Unit = {
    super.checkExit(status)
    throw ExitException(status)
  }
}


abstract class SystemExitSpec extends Specification with BeforeAfterAll {

  sequential

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = System.setSecurityManager(new NoExitSecurityManager())

  override def afterAll(): Unit = System.setSecurityManager(null)
}
```

test **ConverterSpec**

```
import org.specs2.execute.Failure

import scala.io.Source

class ConverterSpec extends SystemExitSpec {

"ConverterSpec" should {

    "empty args" >> {
      try {
        Converter.main(Array[String]())
        Failure("shouldn't read this code")
      } catch {
        case e: ExitException =>
          e.status must_== 1
      }
      1 must_== 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I probably missed this part. Nevertheless, it would be nice to have

`myObject.myFunctionExiting() must throwAn(ExitException(1))`

Comment: sorry for a mess, you should revert your last change, we have to use your proposition, why? because specs2 don't verify status.code, due to an [implementation](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/master/matcher/src/main/scala/org/specs2/matcher/ExceptionMatchers.scala#L47)

Comment: you could check the exception message instead, right?

Comment: or simply uses `must throwAn[ExitException]`

Comment: I can use `must throwA[ExitException]`, but it is not equivalent with

 try {
        myObject.myFunctionExiting() 
        Failure("shouldn't read this code")
      } catch {
        case e: ExitException =>
          e.status must_== 1
      }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121521/discussion-between-sergiusz-kierat-and-ven).

Comment: Why do you test `1 must_== 1`?

Comment: Great answer! 

I confirm that it works with scalatest as well.

Answer (score 1):

First option: use some exception instead of `System.exit`.

Second option: call application in separate thread and check return codes.

Third option: mock `System.exit`. There are many possibilities to do that, mentioned one is quite good.

However, there is no `specs2`-specific pattern to work with `System.exit`. Personally I'd suggest first or second options.

Comment: 1. First option is not acceptable for me.
2. Second option is a bit over-engineered to me and more complex than **system-rules**
3. Third option - same as previous

IMO, using **system-rules** is concise, except that it don't use **specs2** :(

Comment: For third option, you can use mocking library that can mock static classes, e.g. PowerMock.

Comment: Another option is to provide/inject a simple component that itself calls System.exit(), and assert via a standard mocking framework that that component is called correctly