# JRuby - Prevent JVM from exiting

Tags: java, jruby, exit

I'm calling a method from an external library that includes System.exit(), shutting down the JVM when the method is called. Is there a way to prevent the JVM created through JRuby to run System.exit() if encountered?

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything good to come from ignoring `System.exit`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to test methods that call System.exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/java-how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit)

Comment: The only real solution is to complain to the author(s) of that library that they shouldn't be using `System.exit(...)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could install a SecurityManager for the JVM, using JRuby :

```
class SecurityManagerImpl < java.lang.SecurityManager

    def checkExit(status)
      raise java.lang.SecurityException.new("HALTED System.exit(#{status})") if status == 42
    end

    # optionally - disable all other checks from happening :
    superclass.instance_methods(false).select { |name| name.to_s.start_with?('check') }.each do |name|
      class_eval "def #{name}(*args) end" if name != :checkExit
    end

end

java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(SecurityManagerImpl.new)
```

now, all `exit(42)` calls will fail with a `Java::JavaLang::SecurityException (HALTED System.exit(42))` which need to be handled up the call stack.

be aware that this is likely a very "hacky" work-around to have in place ...