# Surefire marks tests as failed when they set SecurityManager

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, securitymanager, java-security-manager

I have some tests that need to check if the main code did a System.exit(...). This works very nicely with suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/309427/1023341. But when running these tests in Jenkins (in stead of in my IDE Eclipse) and later when trying them on the command-line using Maven-Surefire (as Jenkins does) the tests fail without telling me why. It only tells me: `Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log`.

Comment: Can you elaborate why your code is using System.exit(..) ?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I know I should not use System.exit(...) but as I'm using a legacy library that still needs migration there is currently no (cheap) way around this. (It's funny that when ever the System.exit(...) comes up that people ask this question...)

Comment: I would suggest to check this: https://todd.ginsberg.com/post/testing-system-exit/

Comment: Indeed, nice small little solution, though I like the lingo of https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-lambda better. (catchSystemExit)

Answer (score 0):

When setting a SecurityManager during JUnit (5) using System.setSecurityManager and using Surefire plugin, you should restore the SecurityManager after the test.

```
SecurityManager origSecurityManager = System.getSecurityManager();
try {
     // ... code under test here ...
} finally {
     System.setSecurityManager(origSecurityManager);
}
```

or some other more suitable form. This makes sure that Maven-Surefire-plugin stays happy.

**Edit for suggested pre-baked solutions:**

There are two pre-baked libraries for this:

1. [junit5-system-exit](https://github.com/tginsberg/junit5-system-exit)
2. [system-lambda](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-lambda)

As the name suggests: the system-lambda is a Java 8+ solution. Both are JUnit 5 compatible. My personal preference lies with the lambda solution.

[More background information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309396/1023341)

Comment: This is the technical background but indeed there are solutions in libraries as @khmarbaise suggested