# How to make the test methods that call System.exit() are covered with jacoco-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I want to write the unit test of the method just like

```
public void complete() {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I tried these instructions:

- [How to test methods that call System.exit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309396/how-to-test-methods-that-call-system-exit?answertab=scoredesc)
- OR the very details is in : https://www.dontpanicblog.co.uk/2022/10/30/testing-system-exit/

With these ways, the unit test with System.exit is covered 100% when I run it individually. However, when I run it with mvn clean install & jacoco-maven-plugin, it says that the method is not covered in unit test

The problem can be pre-produced with the code on: https://github.com/hotblac/system-exit/tree/junit5
And the jacoco config on pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-check</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>CLASS</element>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>*Test</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>90%</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```